# How to disable File uploader?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to do something like,
When user upload a file,after that I want to make that file uploader disable.
In other word,user will not allow to upload another file once a file is uploded.

I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById(file1).disabled = true;
</script>

<input type="file" name="submission_file" id="file1">
```

But its not working.
How can I do this?

Comment: Are also doing server-side checks? I could easily turn off my JavaScript and get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not placing single qoutes on id

```
document.getElementById('file1').disabled = true;
```

Detailed answer

```
<script>
function diableField()
{
    document.getElementById('file1').disabled = true;
}
window.onload=diableField;

</script>
```

Comment: still it is not working.It shows an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null.Why?

Comment: May be ur script is trying to disable the file field before it loads on page. May be put after your file field loads and better encapsulate in window.load function to make sure your html loads properly.

Comment: @NiraliJoshi check my updated detailed answer. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't quote properly the element ID. Try this:

```
document.getElementById('file1').disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableThis(){
document.getElementById("file1").disabled = true;
}
</script>

<input type="file" name="submission_file" id="file1" onchange="disableThis()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code, i was also face this type of problem, this code was worked for me. hope so it also work for you..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function disableFileUpload(){

document.getElementById("file1").disabled = true;

}
</script>
<input type="file" name="submission_file" id="file1" onchange="disableFileUpload()">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks...